# JSON from PHP to JQuery through AJAX - Security Concerns

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, pdo

Example

I'm using JQuery to make an Ajax call to obtain from the server the value of a username, and then use it to set the value of a textfield.

JQuery code :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "assets/process/getUserData.php",
  data: {"get_username" : 1, "user_id" : user_id},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){

    $('#name-textfield').val(data['username']);
  }
});
```

PHP code :

```
//pdo query to get the value from the db
...
$username = $pdoQuery->fetch();
//$username contains the field 'username'
echo json_encode($username);
```

Considering that $username could contain anything (other than doing a simple trim(), strip_tags() and a prepared statement with pdo, I'm not sanitizing it when i insert it into my db),

Should I use in my PHP code this instead ?

```
htmlentities(json_encode($username), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

or it's not necessary ?

In case it is necessary,

How do I display HTML entities in the textfield correctly? 
(For example, if a username contains a double quote, using the above jQuery code will display `&quot;` instead of `"`).

Thanks.

Comment: No, you shouldn't do that. If you convert the JSON to HTML entities, it won't be valid JSON.

Comment: HTML entities are only necessary in HTML source code. When assigning to the input value in Javascript, it's not necessary to encode it.

Comment: You need to sanitize ALL of the data you INSERT into the database. Data retrieved from the database should already be clean in all cases, if you are doing your inserts correctly. This is not the section of your code that is worrisome from a security standpoint, the part where you put the username in is what should be examined.